# Laravel Cache helper "driver" not implemented

Tags: php, laravel, mocking, mockery

I have a test that is calling a Controller, which literally handles a call to some logic service I mocked.

### The test

```
public function test_it_can_list_all_folders()
{
    $mockedLogicResponse = [
        "id" => 1111,
        "parent_id" => 2222,
        "name" => "Some Name",
        "children" => [
             [
                 "id" => 3333,
                 "parent_id" => 5555,
                 "name" => "Ad-hoc"
             ],
             [
                "id" => 4444,
                "parent_id" => 6666,
                "name" => "Another thing"
            ]
        ]
    ];

    Cache::shouldReceive('has')
        ->once()
        ->with('campaign_folders')
        ->andReturn(false);

    $this->instance(
        Logic::class,
        Mockery::mock(Logic::class, function (MockInterface $mock) use ($mockedLogicResponse) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('fetchData')
                ->once()
                ->andReturn($mockedLogicResponse);
        })
    );

    // httpGet is just a wrapper for a call('GET', ..), it's tested and working fine    
    $response = $this->httpGet($route);

    $response->assertOk(); //This goes well
    $this->assertEquals($mockedLogicResponse, $response->json()); //This goes well too
}
```

### Controller:

```
class LogicController extends Controller {
protected $logic;

public function __construct(Logic $logic)
{
    $this->logic = $logic;
}

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->get('folder_id');

    return $this->logic->fetchData($id);
}
```

}

### Logic:

```
class Logic {
    public function fetchData(string $id): array
    {
        if (Cache::has('folders')) {
            return Cache::get('folders');
        }

        //This is returning correctly the data
        $foldersList = $this->getFolders(...); 

        foreach ($foldersList[$folder['id']] as $folder) {
            $res = [....]; 
            // We perform some irrelevant logic
            $children = ['children' => $res[$folder['id']]];

            $fetchedFolders[] = array_merge($folder, $children);
        }

        Cache::put('folders', $fetchedFolders, 3600);

        return $fetchedFolders;
    }
}
```

The problem(s) are a few, for starters I'm receiving this:

1. `Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException : Received Mockery_2_Illuminate_Cache_CacheManager::driver(), but no expectations were specified`

It's good to point out that I am literally copying an example from the documentation here [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mocking#mocking-facades), so I can't see I'm missing any step.

Also, as the Cache is being called from the mocked logic, but the method is calling them (I dumped the result of the "`has`" Cache method)

2. As I also want to test (In another test) that the `Cache::get()` is begin called when requested the data for a second time, how can I clean the Cache (I set it for an hour), in order to test something like so:

```
Cache::shouldReceive('has')->twice();
Cache::shouldReceive('get')->once();
Cache::shouldReceive('put')->once();
```

Is there any step I am missing? If so, which ones?

UPDATE: After googling a bit, I found [this solution](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10803), which in part solves my testing issues, but I'm concerned why the official documentation is not working, in order to use it instead of a custom solution.

Kind regards

Comment: Why not just use the file driver on the cache for testing purposes? You can still assert what is in that?

Comment: mm I checked in the environment file and the cache is set to file while on tests, so I'm lost. How would that work?

Comment: Just avoid mocking it and use the cache in test like $this->call(...); $this->assertEquals('keyshouldbeset', Cache::get('yourkey'))